# React and Fastify Static - unable to access urls directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fastify

I have my react site which I build from the create-react-app boilerplate.

I'm using the `npm run build` to create the production build then using fastify to serve (along with fastify-static).

My fastify-static code looks like:

```
const DistPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build')
server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: DistPath
})
```

It works on the whole, however if I attempt to go to a page url directly fastify responds with a 404. If I click links from the index page all works fine.

I think I understand why this happens - the build folder only has `index.html`, not a html for each of the page.

I'm curious how can i fix this?

Is there something in fastify I can do. I see the routes has a wildcard but that is already defaulted to a wildcard *.

The other thing I'm wondering, perhaps the react build can be updated so each route is actually outputted in the build folder as a `.html` so fastify-static can return it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Even though it specifically calls out express I think the idea is nearly the same for you. [Serving app with client side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [setDefaultRoute](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#setdefaultroute) method to set up a default route that is used when a 404 might occure otherwise:

```js
const DistPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build')
server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: DistPath
})

const defaultRoute = function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html')
}

server.setDefaultRoute(defaultRoute)
```

Or use the [setNotFoundHandler](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#setnotfoundhandler) to set up the 404 handler, this method givese you a bite more flexibility in the implementation (e.g. filter 404 /api calls so they still result into a 404 - altough I guess you also might be able to do this with the default route approach):

```js
const DistPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build')
server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: DistPath
})

server.setNotFoundHandler((request, reply) => {
    const url = request.raw.url
    if (url !== undefined && url.startsWith('/api')) {
        throw fastify.httpErrors.notFound(`${url} not found`)
    } else {
        void reply.sendFile('index.html')
    }
})
```

Further information about that topic can be found in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/74). I also highly recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8437796) to another question on the same topic.

Comment: looks like `reply.sendFile` no longer exists?